# What do I do with this 'session' created by passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am implementing user authentication and and once they are authenticated, they can CRUD their user data on the database. I can currently authenticate users and have users register a new account, but im not sure what my next step should be. What should my Node server pass back to my front end once my user is authenticated? I read everywhere that I am suppose to use tokens and sessions to check if user is auth for every request.

`Auth.js`

```
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require("passport")


router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(user)
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({errors: err})
        }
        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({errors: "Incorrect username or password"})
        }
        //figure out what this does 
        req.logIn(user, function(err){
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({errors: err});
            }
            return res.status(200).json({success: `Logged in ${user.id}`})
        })

    })(req, res, next)
})

module.exports = router
```

`Setup.js` (for passportjs)

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const User = require('../models/user')
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    })
})

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
        //Match user
        User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                //match password
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        console.log("successfully auth")
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        console.log("incorrect password ")
                        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect Password" })
                    }
                })

            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("no account found")
                return done(null, false, { message: err })
            })
    })
)
module.exports = passport
```

`index.js`

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require('axios');
const User = require('./models/user')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const passport = require("./passport/setup")
const auth = require("./routes/auth")


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI).then(console.log("MongoDB Connection Success")).catch(err => console.log("MongoDB Connection Failed" + err))
// For backend and express init
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(session({
  secret: 'random secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.ATLAS_URI }),
}));


app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use("/auth", auth)

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email
  const plainTextPassword = req.body.password;

  //check if user already exists 
  User.find({ name: email }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser.length === 0) {
      bcrypt.hash(plainTextPassword, 8, async (err, hash) => {
        try {
          const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hash
          });
          let result = await user.save();
          if (result) { 
            console.log("account registered successfully")
            res.send(result)
          }

        } catch (e) {
          res.send("Something Went Wrong");
          console.log("something went wrong ---" + e)
        }
      })
    } else {
      console.log("user account already exists! Login instead. ")
    }
  })

})
```

Im not trying to debug an error, just need to know what the approach is. Basically, I want the user to login once, and then be able to navigate around the web app and crud to their database. Thank you!!

My sessions are stored in a different collection in mongodb but idk what to do with this
[image]

Comment: `tokens and sessions to check if user is auth for every request` that's what's you'd pass back to your client - a token or a session, most often you can send it as a httponly cookie in the login success response ... then, every request made by that client to your server will have the cookie you just set sent along with every request (as long as each request is set as `withCredentials` - but that's client code, so how that's done depends on client code

Comment: i think i understand thank you. but im also confused with why passport is saving my sessions in a different collection. shouldnt it somehow be linked to the `user`'s account. Is it possible or even recommended to put the user's session data in the user's document

Comment: sorry, never used passprot